# Why does the Samsung Galaxy Tab2 7.0 have a built in phone app?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

Why does the Samsung Galaxy Tab2 7.0 have a built in phone app?  It does not have a phone.

Comment: I think 3G one can make phone call.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 versions of Galaxy Tab2 7 - WIFI only and WIFI+3G.

3G version just has a slot to insert your SIM card (near SD slot) and turns your tablet into really big smartphone :)

I've also read, that 3G version is available only in Europe.